# How to improve the speed of marker plotting?

Tags: matlab, plot, trace, imshow

I have a bunch of images where I want to plot a tracing + a marker of 2D positions over time (i.e. 300 images with a tracing going from position (1,1) to (300,300) --> let's assume a straight diagonal line for this purpose.

Plotting this tracing over the image is easily accomplished using the plot function. Plotting the actual tracing is very time consuming. The only way I am able to do it is using `vision.MarkerInserter` and using the `step` function within a loop (for or while):

```
markerInserter = vision.MarkerInserter('Shape','Circle','BorderColor','Custom','CustomBorderColor','red', ...'Fill',1,'FillColor','Custom','CustomFillColor',[255],'Size',6,'Opacity',0.88);

frame = step(markerInserter, frame_copia,[int32(centroidsFiltered(i,2)) int32(centroidsFiltered(i,1))]);
imshow(frame,'Border', 'tight'); hold on

plot(centroidsFiltered(:,2),centroidsFiltered(:,1),colour,'LineWidth',0.5)
```

Is there any faster way of plotting this tracing in the image without using the step or the `vision.markerinserter` functions?

Comment: Please do not change your question into another after someone has already answered. This makes their answer, and thus effort, invalid, and has been explicitly disallowed by moderators, see [this question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290297/5211833). You got an answer to your original question, so please ask another question for your second part.

Comment: Getting the error `Undefined function or variable 'frame_copia'.`

Comment: @Poelie you need to make some image called 'frame_copia'. And only then try the code.

Comment: You should edit your question to use a sample image (e.g. `peppers.png`, `'greens.jpg'`, `'cameraman.tif'` etc) and provide `centroidsFiltered` accordingly to make your problem reproducible. People are more willing to look into the problem when they are able to run the provided code as it is. Btw when you use ellipsis `...`, you stop writing at the same line (except for comments) and continue from the next line which is not the case of your provided code (referring to first line of your code).

Comment: If I got your question correctly, not the plotting of anything, but locating some certain object (=tracing) in the image is time consuming. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using the MarkerInserter class, simply use the built-in `line` function to plot the markers

Comment: Tried that and it indeed speeds up a little bit.